# Report viewer giving error Parameter is not valid on azure any solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-storage

I am using rdlc report with mvc 5 application.When i deploy my application on windows azure then got error on report viewer parameter is not valid.guide me any solution.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got the solution of my problem. i upgrade my azure service plan from shared to basic then all rdlc reports working fine

Comment: Why is this? I'd like to be able to use shared or free.

Comment: actually RDLC reports use GDI+ pdf viewer for display pdf reports. Microsoft disabled GDI+ pdf viewer in windows azure shared or free version. you need to upgrdae ur plan to basic plan from shared plan then your RDLC reports will work perfectly.

Comment: http://kevgriffin.com/word-of-warning-for-people-using-3rd-party-reporting-tools-in-azure/